# Is it okay not to use a hammer drill with tapcon screws?

Tags: drill, brick

I got some tapcon screws to hang a floating shelf in brick. However, reading the directions, I see it says to use a hammer drill for the pilot hole.

I don't have one. Is it going to work fine with a regular drill?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regular drill with a good masonry bit will be fine on soft brick.

If the brick is hard like engineering or blue bricks then you will need a hammer drill.

Comment: I assume it's soft? It's the brick on my home just outside the kitchen.